# In what way(s) is God the Father a father to God the Son? And in what way(s) is God the Son a son?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, christology, persons-of-the-trinity, god-the-father

Every concept and Truth is from the creative mind of God.  This includes what defines a father and a son.  By observation, we can know how God defines a father within His design.

Some examples of these Truths observable in His own design:

- **Every father to ever exist has preceded the begetting of his child.**
- **Every son to ever exist must be begotten at a moment in time.**
- **A son inherits qualities and responsibilities from his father at a *specific moment in time.***

It appears the triune theory removes all aspects of what is defined as sonship and fatherhood.

It also appears that the triune theory adds unique qualities/characteristics to the father/son relationship that are seemingly irrational.  No instances of these qualities can be found anywhere in the design of Creation which is all from the imaginative mind of God.

Some examples:

- **A son never references his father and himself together by using a singular personal pronoun: I, Me, He, Him, Himself. *(Mark 12:26-27, Matt 19:4, Job 38:1, Isaiah 44:24)*

  Rather the plural pronouns "we" and "us" are exclusively used.**
- **A third party never references both a father and his son as 1 non-personified being while also using singular personified pronouns: He, Him, His, Himself. *(Exodus 3:6, Gen 5:27, Isaiah 40:22, Isaiah 42:5, Deut 32:6 )*

  Rather, "they", "them", "theirs" are used.**
- **A son cannot beget himself or be begotten by a non personified essence/nature which is a necessary Trinitarian interpretation of the following verse:**

  *Psalm 2:6 Yet have I set my king upon my holy hill of Zion.
  7 I will declare the decree: YHWH hath said unto me, Thou art my Son; this day have I **begotten** thee*

**Question(s)** - Please answer all to be considered for the bounty.

According to Trinitarians:

1. **In what way(s) is God the Father a father to God the Son?**
2. **In what way(s) is God the Son a son of God the Father?**
3. **If your answer is simply *"the risen Jesus is subordinate to his Father and of the same nature"*, please explain how this makes him more of a son than the angels.**
4. **Of the relational aspects in your answer, which of these overlap with the concept of fatherhood and sonship within the design of nature and more specifically mankind?**

1 John

> 22 Who is a liar but he who denies that Jesus is the Christ? He is antichrist who denies the Father and the Son.

Comment: We've got a great [comment policy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/acceptable-comments-policy-for-christianity-stack-exchange) that people should check out!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147866/discussion-on-question-by-read-less-pray-more-in-what-sense-is-god-the-father-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Please read our comment policy!

Comment: I have down-voted this question because of the reason given by the OP for editing the question: 
changed the word sense to render Nigel's answer a non answer.... This edit IN NO WAY changes my question.

Comment: @Lesley - the edit was made to clarify the question. The question was not about the *human senses*. Like you said, my edit, in no way changed my question.  Nigel's answer was already a non answer.  The edit only made this clear to anyone who is reading.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the words "This edit in no way changes my question" is what YOU said in the reason you gave for changing your question. It still looks to me like the reason you altered your question was for the purpose of invalidating one answer.

Comment: @Lesley.... the mind sees what it want to see.  Read the comment section of Nigels answer to see my first comment.  Then take a gander at my Meta question that is addressing this exact issue.  https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4055/52004

Answer (score 4):

. . . . . . .  'in what sense' . . . . . ?

---

Note after question edit : The 'way' is the same as 'sense'. The words 'Father' and 'Son' *mean something* to them that believe in God. But the concept is not appreciated by those who do not perceive the Spirituality of the Deity.

Changing the word does not alter the matter of perception : the seeing or not seeing of God as he truly is.

---

The human 'senses' are not capable of either perceiving or understanding that which is eternal ; that which is of Spirit ; or that which is Divine.

None of the human 'senses' (which are created, not begotten of Spirit) are able to communicate with the invisible, the unhearable, the untouchable, and the unthinkable.

> But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: *for* *they are foolishness unto him*: **neither can he know them**, because they are spiritually discerned. [1 Corinthians 2:14 KJV]

In other words : the things of God, who is Spirit, **make no sense** to the natural man. Or, according to the edited question : ***the way in which they operate*** is meaningless to the natural man.

This is why the natural heart and mind of man can neither appreciate, nor enter into, the knowledge of Deity ; and, most particularly, the relationship of (as you, yourself, precisely state) 'God, the Father' and 'God, the Son : words which *the human mind* cannot possibly process, there being 'One God'.

And who *shall* perceive these things if they are not born of God and are not, themselves, sons of God ?

> For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, they are the sons of God.
> [Romans 8:14 KJV]

This is the very reason so many struggle with the concepts. That is to say either the 'sense' of them or the 'way' in which they can be understood and rested upon in faith.

As Jesus of Nazareth said 'Ye must be born again'.

> Jesus answered and said unto him, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God. [John 3:3 KJV]

And if not even *the kingdom* can be perceived, how  much *less* the One who sits upon the throne ?

The knowledge of Deity requires repentance, that is to say 'another mind' (*metanoia*) than the carnal mind. And then faith is required, which is a gift of the Spirit, not a natural capacity.

> Then Peter said unto them, Repent, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins, *and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost*. [Acts 2:38 KJV]

> ... for by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: **it is the gift of God**: [Ephesians 2:8 KJV]

So "**in no sense**" is my answer.

Or, according to the edit, the 'way' in which the relationship between 'God, the Father' and 'God, the Son' is perceived **cannot be perceived** by nature but *only by entering into that relationship oneself*, by (Spirit-given) penitence and by (God-given) faith

There is no 'sense' which will aid you in your quest.

There is no 'way' for the natural man to tread upon. Strait is the gate and **narrow is the way** which leadeth unto life. And few there be which find it, said He who, himself, *is that way*, Matthew 7: 13,14.

These deeply spiritual, divine and eternal matters ***make no sense*** to those who are not the sons of God, born of God, by the work of the Spirit in repentance and faith, and gifted by the Spirit - once saved - to enter in fully, in understanding and spiritual apprehension, to the deep things of the eternal, unchanging God who made the heavens and the earth.

---

This knowledge is out of the reach of natural man : a sword turns ***every way***, fiery in nature and wielded by angelic power.

> So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of life. [Genesis 3:24 KJV]

It keeps ***the way*** to the Tree of Life.

> That which is born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit. [John 3:6 KJV]

Only that which is begotten of Holy Spirit can enter in and receive.

Natural man, Adam, is banished and is not only *not permitted* to reach out and grasp at Life, *he is prevented from even attempting to do so.*

---

I write these things as a lifelong Trinitarian (and Protestant) baptised at the age of five, in 1956, voluntarily, into the Church of Scotland (I remember the occasion vividly) and then baptised, again voluntarily, as an adult, into the Baptist Assembly of Scotland at the age of sixteen in 1967.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147919/discussion-on-answer-by-nigel-j-in-what-ways-is-god-the-father-a-father-to-god); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an oversimplification, but here goes.

In Islam, good muslims insist that Allah is one God. To associate any other person with Him and claim this other person is also God is blasphemy to muslims. While **you** are not a muslim, I think you have this "one God" thing in common with muslims. While they do not address Allah as Father, the Judeo-Christian scriptures do.

As the hymn says, "Eternal Father, strong to save . . .." To say that only the Father existed for eternity but the Son did not is an impossibility. If God indeed is love (1 John 4:8), and has been from all eternity, then he MUST have had the Son to love from all eternity.

To say that at **some point in time**, the Father begot the Son is certainly not scriptural. Love cannot exist in a vaccuum. Love requires an object or a person to be loved--a person to receive that love. In other words, God cannot **be** love (again, 1 John 4:8) without an eternal Son **to love**.

As for how the Holy Spirit fits into the doctrine of the trinity, frankly I do not know. What I do know is that the Holy Spirit, who is called by the apostle John "the Advocate" and "the Spirit of prophecy who bears testimony to Jesus” (see John 14:16; 14:26; 15.26; 16:7; and Revelation 19:10) is fully God and is therefore eternal (see Acts 5:3-4).

As difficult as comprehending "three in one" may be, I submit that the Father--however you define His Fatherness--was never alone. Rather, He, the Son, and the Holy Spirit had a love fest going on from all eternity. God could not exist in any other way than as a Triune God: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit (see Matthew 28:19).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to clarify is that Jesus’ sonship has nothing at all to do with biology. In using this language of Father and Son, the scriptures are drawing on 1st century human categories to (try to) describe what the connection is between God the Father and God the Son.

The “son-ship” of Jesus to God the father is primarily a role. It is drawing on the human categories of father and son as they existed in the 1st century and is primarily about rights of inheritance, and the position of representing the father. For example, in ancient times a father could send (especially) his firstborn son as a kind of family ambassador to represent his father in business dealings. In such a role, the son was understood to speak with the full authority of the father and could close deals without having to confirm with the father that he was in agreement.

So, Jesus holds this kind of role with regards to God. When Jesus speaks, the Father speaks.

There is also some sense in which the son, like the Holy Spirit - proceeds from the Father. He is distinct from the Father, yet is of one substance with him.

I don’t think anyone really understands what that means (Trinitarian theology has been wrinkling brains for two millennia now), but it is to be expected that an eternal, infinite God would be far more complicated than finite human brains can make sense of.

All we can do, is make assertions about the relationship, based on the evidence of scripture, in the ways Jesus interacted with God the Father, and the  things his authorised Apostles (who spent several years with him) said was true about God.

Those assertions include that:

1. The Father is God
2. The Son is God
3. The Spirit is God
4. The Father is not the Son or the Spirit
5. The Son is not the Spirit
6. There is only one God

Somehow these six assertions are true, and we can made decisions about how we live assuming their truth, even if we don’t understand how they are true.

Comment: In place of saying "Somehow these six assertions are true," why not present Biblical support for them, assuming such exists?  People here want to know the *reason* for the statement, not merely that you *believe* something to be true.  Upon what basis are those assertions valid?  Apart from the first and the last of those, I expect you will find Biblical support hard to find--non-existent, in fact.

Comment: "the scriptures are drawing on 1st century human categories"..... God is speaking of concepts He laid out since the foundation of the world... fathers and sons.  I see no distinction between how you are describing the sonship of Jesus and godship of angels.

Comment: "The “son-ship” of Jesus to God the father is primarily a role" How can you say "primarily a role" and not be a modalist?

Comment: @Biblasia the question here is not to explain all of Trinitarian theology (Which is what providing the reasons for 6 of those assertions would almost amount to) but specifically the question about the Sonship of the 2nd person in relation to the first, which would touch on #1 and #2 but less directly.

Comment: @esques I am not a modalist, because I qualified the role remark with “primarily” rather than “exclusively”. Talking about God the son, as “a Son” draws attention to the second person of the Trininities son-like relationship with the father which is all about him representing the father, as well as being the heir of all that is the father’s. That’s why the human category of “son” is used to describe it rather than having anything to do with biological reproduction.

Comment: @DavidBuddrige primarily doesn't eliminate the modalist reading -- because when you say son-ship is a role, it suggests a quality that is changeable. "the father which is all about him representing the father" Maybe some who call themselves Trinitarians would agree but not all because that suggests the name son only works in relation to the Incarnation; explaining why the Holy Spirit is not a Son would run into additional challenges

Comment: @eques - I'm mainly referring to the use of the word "son" to describe the second person of the Trinity.  There is a person of the Trinity (called the son) who is not the Father or the Spirit - but who is all God, and there is only one God... but they need to use a word to describe that person, and "Son" is chosen because it describes the relationship better than any other word we have available.  It has nothing to do with biology however, since the second person of the Trinity has always existed, along with the Father than the Spirit.

Comment: @DavidBuddrige I'm sorry but I'm not following your point; it seems you mostly repeated what was in your original answer. I was talking about using the word "role" and how doing so especially in conjunction with the idea that "the son represents the Father" suggests incarnation to define the son-ship. "It has nothing to do with biology" are you saying there is no similarity between the son-ship of Christ and human son-ship? or are you saying that he's not really a son; it's only the "best term" we could come up with?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Bible speaks of one and only one God because the Bible is quite explicit that there is only ONE God. The Father speaks of a Son because according to Him (and to scripture) this God had a Son an extension of Himself of HIS OWN NATURE just like all sons.

The "obvious" problem is many make "the Father" the ONLY reference to "God," when it is a term clearly employed throughout the New Testament to "distinguish" between the Father in His "God-ness,"  the Son in HIS same "God-ness," and the Spirit in His self-same "God-ness."

If "the Father" alone is God, there would be no need to distinguish Him as "the Father" and one would ONLY see the same continued metaphorical applications of that term. But you don't; God is NEVER ONCE identified as "the Father" in the Old Testament (other than in a collective and metaphorical sense).

God was called father (mainly and exclusively) by the Old Testament people because He is their creator. In the New Testament He is constantly so distinguished. so why bother making the distinction if there is no distinction to be made?

Since the Father of Christ is God, then Christ is God--He is the Son of God--who, and like all sons He bears the full ONTOLOGICAL NATURE of His Father. If this is not so, then the Bible is a lie, or at best an incredibly bad case of special pleading requiring that in this ONE instance in all of the universe a son actually does NOT bear the full nature of his own father.

Furthermore, the Son is subordinate to the Father. This is an intentional sonship and does not mean they are not equally God. There was a reason why Jesus Christ Himself often referred to Himself as "the Son of God" and as "the Son of Man." He's the "Son of God" on His Father's side and the "Son of Man" on His mother's side.

Comment: Thank you.  "full ONTOLOGICAL NATURE of His Father"...... Are you talking about now or when he was walking the dry land?  How is his glorified ontological nature different (if at all) to the rest of the children of God?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly... Your answer is that Jesus is a son to the Father because he is subordinate and of the same nature....... So like an angel?

Comment: No, you do not understand me. We are sons of God by adoption. Read Romans 8:14-17 and Galatians 4:3-7. Jesus on the other hand is the one and only unique Son of God. At John 1:18, 3:16 and 1 John 4:9. The Bible tells us that Jesus Christ is the only begotten Son of God. That would mean, by definition, that God did not beget Satan and everyone in human history as his "sons." Philippians 2:5-8 explains it. When Jesus was "SENT" from heaven, (not created) He voluntarily subordinated Himself to His Father in position, not in nature. We are subordinated to our parents in position, not in our nature

Comment: I'm not speaking of the process by which ***we will be like him***.  Paul says adoption yet Jesus says "reborn" and John says "born of God".   I'm inquiring about any **difference in ontological nature between the glorified children of God and the preeminent son of God**.  What is the difference in their final ontology?

Comment: I just made a new q. 
 >> https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96230/will-all-glorified-children-of-god-take-on-the-title-of-yhwh-in-the-age-to-come

Comment: There's a "HUGE" difference! Like I stated Christians are adopted sons of God by way of being born again. Jesus is the Son of God by nature because He did not have to be born again, He was sinless and perfect. 1 Peter 2:22, "Who committed no sin, nor was any deceit found in His mouth." You can also read 2 Corinthians 5:21 and Hebrews 4:15. Another thing why Jesus was not created is the fact that He was sent from heaven. John 3:13, John 6:38, "For I have come down from heaven, not to do My own will, but the will of Him who sent Me." Read John 6:41 and John 6:50.  Do you know any sinless people?

Comment: Again.... I'm speaking of the age to come.  Our glorified nature of godhood.  Not mankind's fallen state.

Comment: Well tell me, how does one qualify to enter the age to come? You have to be born again here on earth before one enters glory. 2 Peter 1:3-4, "seeing that His divine power has granted to us everything pertaining to life and godliness, through the true knowledge of Him who called us by His own glory and excellence. Vs4, For by these He has granted promises, in order that by them you might become PARTAKERS of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world by lust." So, are you telling me that you partaking of a divine nature makes your godhood just like Jesus Christ?

Comment: *"So, are you telling me that you partaking of a divine nature makes your godhood just like Jesus Christ?"*  I'm not telling.... I'm literally asking this in this very question. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96230/will-all-glorified-children-of-god-take-on-the-title-of-yhwh-in-the-age-to-come

Comment: And I literally answered with a resounding NO. We were created by Jesus Christ, end of story.

Comment: Please answer the question.  I posted it just for you to have the opportunity to explain how our nature is different from the preeminent son of God in the age to come.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**
Let's begin by assuming these three statements are correct:

- Every father to ever exist has preceded the begetting of his child.
- Every son to ever exist must be begotten at a moment in time.
- A son inherits qualities and responsibilities from his father at a specific moment in time.

These may be displayed graphically on a time-line:
[image]

The first dotted line depicts a point in time at which the son comes into existence. The second shows the point at which qualities and responsibilities are inherited.<sup>`1`</sup>

However, the OP improperly uses the **title** of "father" **before** there is a son. Yes, every father pre-exists every son, but until there is a first son, he who **will be** father, lacks that title:

[image]

It is at the same moment in time the first son is begotten the title of "father" may be used. Before then the proper title is "not a father" or "desires to be a father." Despite all intention and desire, he who is without a child is not a father.

**Son of God**
If we believe the Son of God was not eternal, then prior to His existence, God was without Son.<sup>`2`</sup>Therefore, the title of "Father" cannot be used with God, until the moment in time there is a Son. Just as the Son has a specific point at which He was begotten, God had a specific point in time at which He **became** Father:

[image]

Since God **became** something different, Father, when the Son came into existence, God must have been something less, "God," until He **became** Father. The problem with this is obvious.

On the other hand, if we understand the title of Father as one which may be used of God from all eternity past, then God must have had a Son from all eternity past:

[image]

The only way to recognize God the Father as always and eternally "Father" is is to recognize the Son is always and eternally "Son."

---

<sub>1. The two are illustrated taking place at different times. Both could take place at the same time.</sub>
<sub>2. The same is true if angels or some other being is created first. Before God creates the first which may be called son, God cannot be called "Father."</sub>

Comment: He called Israel His first born son.  Jesus is not His first son.  Jesus is His only Begotten son.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore The logic is the same whether you use the Son of God or Israel. Prior to having a Son (Jesus or Israel) God was not the Father. Whether His first son was created or adopted, He was childless until He acted. Therefore, God **became** the Father at some point in time, and using your reasoning, Abraham and Isaac were not His children and could not call Him Father. Moreover, if YHVH is correctly called Father, then He must have had a Son. And if Jesus is the firstborn, then Jesus pre-existed Israel.

Comment: YHWH is called the Father numerous times in the OT. ***He was already known as the Father who created and established everything.*** This question, however, is specifically asking how is God the Father a father to God the Son....not the entire creation..... (What about the sons of God who had children with the daughters of man?)  YHWH became a Father when He first created.  He is thee Father because He is the only eternal person,  therefore, everything is father'd by Him.  But this q is specific to His unique fatherhood of His only begotten.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore *He is the firstborn of all creation*. Pretty clear. **After** He had a Son He could be called Father. If your defense is He is called Father throughout the OT, then you are simply affirming Colossians 1:15. **After** He has Son, **then** He was called Father. Without a Son, **not** the Father.

Comment: The angels were created before mankind.  At the moment of creating them, YHWH became a father.  *Firstborn of all creation*... this is the new creation.  Now, the Risen Son, is the first glorified of the New Creation. One that will eventually, in the Father’s timing, completely encompass and restore the corrupted first creation and all its creatures. In this way, Paul is speaking in a timeless way by declaring the Risen Son as the first born of all creation. All creation IS the New Creation in eternity.

Comment: Col 1 15 He(the Risen Son) is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. 16 For by (the Risen Son) all things were created that are in heaven and that are on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or powers. All things were created through (the Risen Son) and for (the Risen Son). 17 And (the Risen Son) is before all things, and in (the Risen Son) all things consist. 18 And (the Risen Son) is the head of the body, the church, who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead, that in all things (the Risen Son) may have the preeminence.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore If He has no Son He cannot be called Father. As for the angels, there is no Scripture where angels call God "Father." However, even then you run into the same problem. If God must create that which is Son, then God is not Father until after He acts. It does not matter what you choose, angels, Jesus, Israel, or anything else. God does not become Father until after there is Son. You recognize God as eternal Father, but you want to give Him that title before there is Son. But as your question correctly notes, no Son = no Father. OTOH eternal Father = eternal Son. Quite simple.

Comment: He is called Father by Israel, His first born son.  They are the first ones to call Him Father.  Angels are referenced as sons of God is my point.  When YHWH acted and created is the moment He became a father by fathering ALL life.  YHWH is eternal and He is a Father.  So He is the Eternal Father and Farmer btw.   But He is not eternally a father because before He created anything.... He was alone.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Without a Son God cannot be called Father. He is simply God. YHVH is eternal yes, but unless His Son is eternal, He **became** Father, regardless of what you choose to say is first.

Comment: Yes!  He became a Father.   Just like every father.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147828/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-read-less-pray-more).

Comment: @RevelationLad: You cannot say that  "God became the Father at some point in time" because the Son of God was the Son of God from eternity. Eternity is not a bunch of time, but a state of being that has no beginning and no end.  Jesus, in becoming the Son of Man, veiled his God-ness in becoming human (though the apostles, and others, witnessed in Jesus that God-ness in the signs and wonders he performed in time and space. The great kenosis (Philippians 2)

Comment: in no way lessened his deity; rather, it made his deity visible and observable in time and space. His great humility in becoming the Son of Man did not change his nature as fully God, but it did demonstrate in time and space the eternal truth of his Sonship. As the apostle Paul observed, under the influence of the Holy Spirit, "So it is written: 'The first man Adam became a living being'; the last Adam, a life-giving spirit'" (1 Corinthians 15:45 NIV).

Comment: Furthermore, "And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifest in the flesh, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world, received up into glory" (1 Timothy 3:16 KJV).

Comment: @rhetorician I agree with you. When I say God became the Father at some point in time, I am reasoning from the OP’s POV. The falsity of that reasoning is obvious as you point and as I attempt to show. If the Son is not eternal, then the term Father cannot be eternal. If the term Father is eternal, it is only because the Son is eternal. One defines the other.

Comment: @RevelationLad: Good point, and good observation. Don

Answer (score -1):

(*I'll interpret the use of "Trinity" and "Trinitarian" in this question broadly, as meaning non-unitarian (to include the binitarian view), since neither the question nor this answer involve any aspect of a third person.

But if the question* does *require the 3-in-1 doctrine, I doubt it will get a satisfying answer.*)

#### In what sense is God the Father a father to God the Son?

Their relationship is the very *definition* of what the physical human relationship only symbolizes.

#### In what sense is God the Son a son of God the Father?

Human fathers and sons are physically and mentally very similar.

At least they are on the average.
Yes, one might be a little taller, or slightly better at playing a piano, or …, but those are minor random variations.
Humans are made in the image of God, but as physical beings they are only imperfect physical analogues of what God actually is.
And yes, humans *do* change with age (a father is physically and mentally superior to an infant, and a son physically and mentally superior to a feeble old man).
The point is that *there is not necessarily anything that inherently makes one superior to the other*.

The Father and Son are eternal and do not change or age, and they *are* very similar in every way, having the same form and possessing the same abilities.
Each of them is "God":

- [Jesus] said also that God was his Father, making himself equal with God. — John 5:18
- I and my Father are one. — John 10:30
- he that hath seen me hath seen the Father — John 14:9

Both for imperfect father/son and for perfect Father/Son though, the fundamental attribute that distinguishes their relationship is an attitude of respect and deference on the part of the son.

#### If your answer is simply "the risen Jesus is subordinate to his Father and of the same nature", please explain how this makes him more of a son than the angels.

No created angel can ever be like the Father.
Angels *are* spirit rather than flesh, but angels are *not* of the same nature as God; even ignoring their limited spiritual power, they simply do not have God's personality.
("*For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou art my Son, this day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him a Father, and he shall be to me a Son?*" — Hebrews 1:5)

But, just as a human son is of the same kind as his human father, the Son is of the same kind as the Father.
The Son and Father have always shared the same power, ability, and personality, but the Son defers authority to the Father.

#### Of the relational aspects in your answer, which of these overlap with the concept of fatherhood and sonship within the design of nature and more specifically mankind?

All of them.
The entire relationship between parents and children is a type of the relationship between the Father and the Son.
This is not an accident; the family is God's deliberate creation.

From a Christian perspective, the entire purpose of life is to enter into that same relationship, preparing one's spiritual self to be reborn as an immortal spirit being, a younger sibling of the Son ("*the firstborn among many brethren*" — Romans 8:29), who as the eldest child holds a position deserving respect and deference.

Comment: Thanks Ray.  Can you elaborate on point 1?  Also, How does Hebrews 1:5 mean that angels are not the same nature as God?  Jesus says we will be like the angels.  Scripture says we will share in the divine nature.  And lastly, How is Jesus equal to his God?  He is a servant of his God to death.  Jesus says his Father is greater than himself.

Comment: Regarding point 2: "*Human fathers and sons are physically and mentally equal.*"  Huh?  No 2 natural object created are equal.  NONE.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, I've clarified what I mean by "equal".

Comment: "*The point is that there is nothing that inherently makes one necessarily superior to the other.*'  How so?  God is not woke.  He creates everyone unique different - unequal.

Comment: "*But the Son is, in every way, equal to the Father, and always has been; he simply chooses to defer to him.*"  Jesus says his Father is greater than himself.  He says he does NOTHING of himself and at the end he submits to his God and Father.  In what sense are they equal?

Comment: "*his Father is greater than himself. He says he does NOTHING of himself and at the end he submits to his God and Father.*"
— Isn't that the definition of the relationship between father and son in a traditional close family?
¶ "*In what sense are they equal?*"
— In the same sense that an army general outranks a colonel, regardless of any personal similarities or differences between the individual people.
There is a mutual understanding that one outranks the other.
Families work the same way.
The Father and Son are equal in every possible way, except that one outranks the other.

Comment: *"Isn't that the definition of the relationship between father and son in a traditional close family?"*  Not exclusively.  Without further context, this same statement can define a slave/servant or someone who is perfectly obedient by choice out of love of his/her superior.  "*except that one outranks the other"*.  Not just outranks but ALL Spirit, power, and authority over the entire Creation proceeds from the Father.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore, the main problem seems to have been my use of the word "equal".  Equality is irrelevant for answering your question (and perhaps is irrelevant in general), so I've removed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Can you elaborate on point 1? Also, How does Hebrews 1:5 mean that angels are not the same nature as God? Jesus says we will be like the angels. Scripture says we will share in the divine nature.

Comment: You are the ***only one*** who attempted to answer all the questions so you get the bounty.  I see major holes in your explanation but rules are rules.  I hope you continue to improve this answer.