# Will all glorified children of God take on the title/name of YHWH in the age to come?

Tags: trinity, nature-of-man, persons-of-the-trinity, divinity

God is 1.  I think we can all agree with Jesus' most important commandment... the Shema.

I've been told here by the most prudent of Trinitarians, that YHWH is not a being or a person, but instead 3 persons sharing the 1 divine essence/nature.

If this is the Truth, then that which is of the quantity 1 must be the non personified divine essence/nature. (Not my belief but taken from top voted answers to my previous questions)

We are told in scripture that after our resurrection, we too will share in the same nature as our master, Jesus Christ, for we will be like him.  He is the first of many.

2 Peter 1:4.

> ...by which have been given to us exceedingly great and precious promises, that through these **you may be partakers of the divine nature**, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through lust.

Eph 3

> 14 For this reason I bow my knees to the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, 15 from whom the whole family in heaven and earth is named, 16 that He would grant you, according to the riches of His glory, to be strengthened with might through His Spirit in the inner man, 17 that Christ may dwell in your hearts through faith; that you, being rooted and grounded in love, 18 may be able to comprehend with all the saints what is the width and length and depth and height— 19 to know the love of Christ which passes knowledge; ***you may be filled with all the fullness of God.***

1 John 3:2

> Beloved, *now we are children of God*; and it has not yet been revealed what *we shall be*, but we know that when He is revealed, **we shall be like Him**, for we shall see Him as He is.

Romans 8

> 29 For whom He foreknew, He also predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son, that He might be the **firstborn among many brethren**.

John 1

> 12 But as many as received Him, to them He gave the right *to become children of God*, to those who believe in His name: 13 who were born, not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, **but of God.**

This progression of reason easily leads one to the the next questions.

According to Trinitarians:

1. ***What is the difference (if any) between the final ontologies of the Preeminent son of God and the rest of the children of God?***
   (Please support your answer with scripture.)
2. ***If no difference exists.... Will all the glorified children of God be the 1 YHWH; the 1 non-personified deity comprised of all persons who share in this unique divine nature?***

Comment: Another relevant verse: John 17:21

Comment: @SamuelBradshaw I almost included that... I literally edited it out of my draft because I think it could be debated that Jesus is speaking of a oneness we can have in this age.  This particular question is strictly speaking of the age to come.  But I agree... we can interpret the glory Jesus has already shared with all the children as the same glory he had with the Father and is about to receive in the literal sense.    But... when do the children receive it in the literal sense.  Its just makes the q a little less clear and concise.

Comment: Well if your going to use this line of reasoning by equating yourself with the ontological  nature of Jesus Christ are you going to be worshipped as He is? Please read Revelation 5:1-14 and Revelation 19:1-8. Are you also identified as "Almighty God" at Revelation 1:8? Do you have any part in being the "Alpha and the Omega" or the "first and last" at Revelation 17-18 or at Revelation 22:13? And here's an oldie but goody at Revelation 4:8-11 and at Revelation 5:1-14. Who's being worshipped?

Comment: @Mr.Bond this question is scoped for the line of reasoning of Trinitarians not myself.  Please ask a separate q and I will answer all your queries.

Comment: "*YHWH, the 1 non-personified deity comprised of all persons who share in this unique divine nature*" — what is the basis of this claim, that Catholics use YHWH to refer to the full Trinity and not strictly to the person of the Trinity that interacted with humanity in the Hebrew scriptures?

Comment: I'm basing this from the top voted answers to my previous questions that overwhelming support this belief.

Comment: None of those verses refer to humans taking on any of the titles of God, nor the nature of God. This question is a non sequitur.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have another question that is asking if YHWH is the 1 Nature or 1 person or 1 being or 1______.    I'm told that the trinity, YHWH, is defined as the 3 persons who share in the God nature.  And its also a held belief that we will share in that same nature.  So it begs this question.

Comment: "And its also a held belief that we will share in that same nature." I'm not aware of any Trinitarians who would teach this. The Orthodox teaching of deification comes closest, but I'm sure they would deny that we actually personally will possess the divine nature ourselves.

Comment: @curiousdannii Nigel agreed to this in more than 1 of my previous questions.  I also think scripture is fairly clear in this regard.  Jesus being the first of many.  The first fruits, we being conformed to his image... and verses I quoted here.  There are many more.  But I see your point, which is why its a 2 part question.

Comment: We are conformed to the Image of Christ, but we never personally take on the divine nature or become divine ourselves. We are God's creations and cannot cross the creator-creation divide.

Comment: John says we become children of God.  Born of God.  We become eternal without end.  We become one with the Father and the Son, just as the Son is.  We become one in Spirit.  We are woshipped in the age to come.  I think we become exactly like our brother.  Not exactly like our Father.  Jesus is not exactly like his Father either.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore It would be nice if you would give the exact references when you post so it can be verified.  Where does John say, "We are worshipped in the age to come?" If that's true why does Jesus say we are to worship God and serve Him only? Luke 4:8. And Jesus is exactly like His Father in nature, this according to John 10:30. "I and My Father we are one." If the Father and His Son are not one in nature the Jews would not have accused Jesus of blasphemy at John 10:31-33 for Jesus making Himself God." Or at John 5:18 where the Jews accuse Jesus of being "equal" with God.

Comment: @Mr.Bond....John is quoting an angel from Jesus who is relaying the revelation given to him by the Father.  *Revelation 3:9 
Behold, I will make them of the synagogue of Satan, which say they are Jews, and are not, but do lie; behold, I will make them to come and **worship before thy feet**, and to know that I have loved thee.*...... Regarding John 10:30.  In John 17:21-23, Jesus says all the children are to be ONE as he and the Father are also ONE.  And in John 5:18... Surprise! the Jews were wrong as they were in a habit of being wrong.

Comment: This inquiry requires to be reduced and focused. It is attempting far too much all at once, covering multiple aspects of the doctrine of Christ.

Comment: @NigelJ It is a complex problem.  Complex problems and ideas require more complex questions to arrive at an understanding.  What of the question, do you disagree with?  I formed the q out of your top voted answers and comments to my previous questions.

Comment: This whole question is based on the unsupported assumption that YHWH is a title and not a name. Until the question can provide support for this claim, it is simply soliciting speculation and opinion.

Comment: @RayButterworth  Fixed...I'd recommend not missing the forest for the trees... This question is not about if YHWH is a name or title(which isn't even agreed upon).... Its about the final ontology of the children.

Comment: We are created in God's image and yet are not exactly like Him.  Some will be conformed to the image of Christ.  I think it is a mistake to assume they will be exactly like Him.

Comment: @MikeBorden Ontologically we will be the same.  But he will always be preeminent.  He will not always be our King.  The Risen Son gives the Kingdom back to the Father.

Answer (score 3):

**YHWH is not a title, it is a name.**

Exodus 3:14.

So no matter what happens to the children of God, they will not actually become the entity we call God. As such they will not be called YHWH.

Names denote specific beings. Beings do not take on the names of other beings, even if they become like them. When Prince Charles became king he did not start being called 'Elizabeth'.

In Trinitarian theology there is a difference between the *begotten* Son of God (Jesus) and any status we have as children of God. Being children of God does not make us *begotten* children of God, nor make us part of the deity.

Comment: I agree.  YHWH is the name of the 1 God.  But I also believe He is a person and people have names.  I used the word *title* because many trinitarians believe the 1 God to be instead the 1 Deity which is not a person or being but a Nature shared by 3 persons.  2 of these persons have their own names.  1 of which is the name of Jesus.  I'm told Jesus is called YHWH because he shares in this divine Nature; the same nature of the rest of the children.  Why do you place a distinction here?  Can you support this answer with any scripture?

Comment: Trinitarians, like me, are going to tell you that YHWH is a name. If you are calling YHWH a "title" because that's what you think Trinitarians believe then please don't.

Comment: Can you define the difference between the 2?  Titles vs names?

Comment: Names apply to specific people/entities. Titles are given someone due to a position they hold, and are changeable from person to person.

Comment: It seems like YHWH is a title for most Trinitarians based on your definitions.

Comment: That's not the case.

Comment: @NigelJ says "*'Jehovah' is a title.*".  Yet [CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Jehovah (Yahweh)](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08329a.htm#:~:text=The%20proper%20name%20of%20God) says that it is "*the proper name of God*", and makes no mention of its being used as a title. What support is there for its being a title?

Comment: " 1 God to be instead the 1 Deity which is not a person or being" Who stated it like that? There's no "instead" and God is definitely a being.

Comment: @NigelJ You maybe think that, but Trinitarians (98% of Christians) don't. The question is about Trinitarian views.

Comment: The Father is YHWH, the Son is YHWH, and the Holy Spirit is YHWH. There are three persons who are YHWH, but only one God who is YHWH.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers say what our new names **will not be**. Revelation tells us what our new names **will be**:

> 17 He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the
> churches. To the one who conquers I will give some of the hidden
> manna, and I will give him a white stone, with **a new name** written on
> the stone that **no one knows except the one who receives it**.’
> (Revelation 2:17)

The implication is that each believer will receive a new and distinct name, just as Abraham did, and Jacob, and others in the Bible. That name is a secret. Since the names will be distinct and define the core identity of the person, they must not be the same, so therefore at most one person can be named Yahweh, and that name is already taken.

Whatever a person's new name will be, the important thing is that it will be a secret known only to that person and God. If secret, we can't know it and the larger question of what each of us will be named is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

## Becoming like Gods

To share in the divine nature means to become like God(s), as mentioned in the [Gen 3:22](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/3-22.htm) (see Cambridge commentary), this refers to immortality, to [live eternally](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=eternal%20life&t=RSV#s=s_primary_0_1). It does not mean becoming God the way he is, or possessing his identity, authority and powers; it is merely an analogous reference.

> `NJB` Then Yahweh God said, 'Now that the man has become like one of us in knowing good from evil, he must not be allowed to reach out his hand and pick from the tree of life too, and eat and live for ever!'

Man legally earns the divine nature of immortality, sharing in the [tree of life](http://juchre.org/articles/book.htm), through obedience to God. On 2 Peter 1:4 (cf. 1Pet 5:10), the [NABRE Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+pet+1&version=NABRE) notes:

> Christian life in its fullness is a gift of divine power effecting a knowledge of Christ and the bestowal of divine promises (2 Pt 3:4, 9). To share in the divine nature, escaping from a corrupt world, is a thought found elsewhere in the Bible but expressed only here in such Hellenistic terms, since it is said to be accomplished through knowledge (2 Pt 1:3); cf. 2 Pt 1:2; 2:20; but see also Jn 15:4; 17:22–23; Rom 8:14–17; Heb 3:14; 1 Jn 1:3; 3:2.

## Be like Angels

"For at the resurrection men and women do not marry; no, they are like the angels in heaven" (Matt 22:30). The immortality of the glorified souls reflects God's nature in us, but God alone is without a beginning or end, being eternal in his *essence*, that is his essential property. Christ is eternal in the sense that divinity is his essential property. While being like the divine angels, we still remain subordinate creatures under authority of God; we should not think that angels are equal with God. Perhaps, this is why the NT authors were careful to present Jesus as greater than mere angels, they presented him as the logos, memra of God, the [Metatron](https://www.biblestudying.net/history-of-judaism7.html). They were careful in showing him one with God the father, in that he was neither created nor a begotten smaller being.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I agree.  But how is this any different than our brother and master, Jesus the preeminent Risen Son?  Is there scripture that says his divinity is different than ours will be?

Comment: I will edit and add the key details soon

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not! How could they? Common sense dictates there is only one YHWH. Besides that the name Yahweh comes from the Hebrew word for "I am."

This is verified at Exodus 3:13-15, when Moses said to God, "Behold, I am going to the sons of Israel, and I shall say to them, "The God of your fathers has sent me to you. Now they may say to me, "What is His name?" What shall I say to them?"

Vs14, "And God said to Moses, "I AM WHO I AM"; and He said, "Thus you shall say to the sons of Israel, "I AM has sent me to you." Vs15, "And God, furthermore, said to Moses, "Thus you shall say to the sons of Israel, The Lord, the God of your fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you." This is My name forever, and this is My memorial-name to all generations.

Now, you made the following statement, "We are told in scripture that after our resurrection, we too will share in the same nature as our master, Jesus Christ, for we will be like him. He is the first of many."

This statemen is also not true. The various verses you quoted to support your statement happens "BEFORE" the resurrection. When one is born again he receives the Holy Spirit of God which like the Apostle Peter stated at 2 Peter 1:4, "by which have been given to us exceedingly great and precious promises, that through these you may be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through lust."

You also made this statement: "What is the difference (if any) between the final ontologies of the Preeminent son of God and the rest of the children of God?"

The main difference is the fact that Jesus Christ has two natures, one of deity on His Father's side and one of human on His mother's side." Mankind has only one nature which is human. You ask for verification  and it can be found at Philippians 2:5-10. Also, some of the Apostles like John, Peter, and Paul identified Jesus Christ as God, including Thomas at John 20:28.

John at John 1:1-3, Paul at Titus 2:13, Peter as 2 Peter 2:1. Oh yea, and by Jesus' own Father at Hebrews 1:8. And for the record YHWH is ONE being who chose to manifest Himself in Scripture as three distinct persons. If you want, start a thread on this and I will prove it. I can also prove that Jesus Christ, the Son of God preexisted His incarnation before He became a permanent man.

Comment: *"I will prove it."*... Nothing is EVER proven.  We interpret observations to strengthen and weaken our concepts.... Hubris is not becoming of the children of God who understand they know nothing in respect to what God knows... Do you think you know something?

Comment: I find your answer to be very dishonest. *" The various verses you quoted to support your statement happens "BEFORE" the resurrection."*  >>> This statement ignores my reference to 1 John 3:2 and Romans 8:29.... and btw YHWH means "I AM"  not "WE ARE".

Comment: Be careful there Read Less Pray More. There's a big difference between "confidence" and pride. And who told you "Nothing is EVER proven?" The proper way to determine proof is to understand what IS said. I cannot show you the verse that says, "Peter and Paul were  Christians." Shall we then use your damaged logic and say that these apostles were not saved? If I were to ask you to prove that Jesus Christ resurrected from the dead how would you do it? Or, how would you prove that Abraham Lincoln was a real person that existed? Lastly, I don't understand your "sub" question. Can you clear it up?

Comment: God requires faith.  NOT proof.  If there were proof, there would be no need for the faith.  The sub question is on a different question.  The one about the Trinity ontology.